# Array exists and is populated but cannot access individual elements on AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm executing an AJAX call in my website running on WordPress 4.7.2. I'm returning an array back from the PHP function which handles the request, with `wp_json_encode()`. When I print the data **array** in the AJAX `success` function it's exactly as expected. But it gives me `undefined` when I try to print the **individual element** inside the array.

The PHP handler function is like this

```
function ajaxHandler(){
     //do something
     $ret = array( 'score'=>$score );
     echo wp_json_encode( $ret );
     wp_die();
}
```

And in my AJAX,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {'action': $my_Action},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data["score"]);
        //also tried console.log(data.score) with same result
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log("not successful");
    }
});
```

The console log in Chrome

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the response data into javascript object inside success callback :

```
success: function(data) {
    var data = JSON.parse( data );
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data["score"]);
    //also tried console.log(data.score) with same result
}
```

Another way is, put `dataType : 'json'` inside ajax properties :

```
$.ajax({
  .....
  .....
  dataType : 'json',
  ......
});
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks. Forgot that I'm sending a JSON back.